# Should I encode HTTP request headers?

Tags: rest, http, networking

I know that URLs need to be encoded before sent to server. But do I need to encode HTTP request headers as well? I'm sending a base64 string in a header that contains = as %3d .. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

The field value restrictions are similar, but not exactly the same. For instance, you can't use bare "%", or "<" and ">" in a URI, but you can use them in a header field value.